# Apache installer question

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, installation

I'm currently using:

> msiexec /i httpd.msi /passive
>   ALLUSERS=1 SERVERADMIN=admin@localhost
>   SERVERNAME=localhost
>   SERVERDOMAIN=localhost
>   SERVERPORT=80
>   INSTALLDIR=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\apache

To install apache without much input, however I don't want to install the Apache Monitor that comes with the .msi. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ADDLOCAL= to select features like this (ApacheMonitoring feature was removed from the list):

`msiexec /i httpd-2.2.17-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8o.msi /passive ALLUSERS=1 SERVERADMIN=admin@localhost SERVERNAME=localhost SERVERDOMAIN=localhost SERVERPORT=80 INSTALLDIR=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\apache ADDLOCAL=ApacheDocs,ApacheRuntime,Apache,BuildFiles,Iconv,OpensslBin,SslBin`

You can use for example SuperOrca to see the features of a .msi file

Comment: I was already checking msiexec /I httpd.msi /L*v ApacheInstaller.log like so. But was still trying to figure the default values for it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: +1 Beat me by ~20 seconds.  `ADDLOCAL` and the `Feature` table within the MSI are your friends.

Comment: Yeah, a crazy place! I need some reputation as I will probably have some questions.